# Meshing a 2D polygon

Tags: cgal

I am struggling to get something like Figure 51.1 in http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/index.html. I could not find an example that generates such mesh. Can you share?

I was able to mesh and refine a polygon, but I am missing properly setting the boundaries and the empty parts.

Thanks

Comment: Did you use seeds to mark holes? See [that example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/index.html#title13). See also [this figure](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/index.html#fig__Domainseeds) illustrating the usage of seeds.

Comment: Cool. That helps.

A little further: I am willing to refine along some edges. (something like the thumbnail picture of this section http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/group__PkgMesh2.html). I am convinced I have to use a SizingField, but I have not found a simple example to get inspiration. Would you have any?

So you understand: I have a reservoir with a well and a fracture. Something like (http://ascelibrary.org/cms/attachment/12625/311682/figure2.gif or https://benthamopen.com/contents/figures/TOPEJ/TOPEJ-9-72_F4.jpg). I need extreme refinement around the fracture.

Comment: This question should have provided a minimum working example of some sort.